# Change hard drive being used?

Tags: centos, hard-drive

I'm going to have another hard drive installed in my server, how can I make it so files are stored on the second hard drive as oppose to the first one, but have the files still accessible as usual on the first hard drive.

Comment: OS? RAID? Volume management in use?

Comment: Which files? Operating System files? Data files? Database store? Do you want to use RAID? Or links? What is the goal?

Comment: This question is pretty much impossible to answer if we don't know your OS.

Comment: sorry, it's just storage no raid or anything. and I'm using centos.

Comment: You haven't added much of the information requested - but if I understand rightly, you could try looking at rsync (using symbolic links) or using symbolic links to link a directory from one drive to the other. Still need to explain what it is you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Need more info....  Question fail.

Comment: basically I have a server for storing videos and hard drive #1 is full, so I want to add another hard drive in.

Comment: What you want is to have been using LVM in the first place. Then it's easy. Maybe you were — but we can't tell from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using LVM? Then you can move the logical volume to the other drive.

- `pvcreate` on the 2nd drive
- `vgextend` the volume group
- `pvmove` the logical volume between drives
- `pvremove` the 1st drive from volume group

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a bind mount.

From [`man mount`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> The bind mounts.
>   Since Linux 2.4.0 it is possible to remount  part  of  the  file
>   hierarchy somewhere else. The call is
>
> ```
>                  mount --bind olddir newdir
> ```
>
> or shortoption
>
> ```
>                  mount -B olddir newdir
> ```
>
> or fstab entry is:
>
> ```
>                  /olddir  /newdir  none  bind
> ```
>
> After  this  call the same contents is accessible in two places.
>   One can also remount a single file (on a single file).
>
> This call attaches only (part of) a single filesystem, not  possible  submounts.  The entire file hierarchy including submounts
>   is attached a second place using
>
> ```
>                  mount --rbind olddir newdir
> ```
>
> or shortoption
>
> ```
>                  mount -R olddir newdir
> ```
>
> Note that the filesystem mount options will remain the  same  as
>   those  on  the  original  mount  point, and cannot be changed by
>   passing the -o option along with --bind/--rbind.